# Maximum no of Host's possible in private network on class wise?

Tags: lan, private-vlan

my query is that what is the maximum no of host's are possible for Private network in class wise.
i.e i want to know No of Private host's in CLASS A,B,C?
how to calculate these no?

Comment: Classfull networks are dead, killed by CIDR 25 years ago. Forget about them.

Answer (score 2):

For classful networks, the available addresses are given by the [Wikipedia page on Classful Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network).

Class A = 16,777,214

Class B = 65534

Class C = 254

The Wikipedia page also discusses the calculation:

> The number of addresses usable for addressing specific hosts in each network is always 2<sup>N</sup> - 2, where N is the number of rest field bits, and the subtraction of 2 adjusts for the use of the all-bits-zero host portion for network address and the all-bits-one host portion as a broadcast address. Thus, for a Class C address with 8 bits available in the host field, the number of hosts is 254.

As Zac67 points out in the comments, [/31 subnets](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3021.txt) differ in the calculation as there is no network and broadcast address. With /32 a single host is defined. These subnets are not available in classful networks but I'm adding them here for completeness.

It's worth noting that nobody uses classful networks anymore.

Comment: it's 2^n-2 for /0 to /30. /31 has no subnet and broadcast addresses, leaving 2 usable host addresses

Comment: @Zac67 You are correct; however, the question and the Wikipedia page talk about classful addressing in which /31 subnets are not possible. Classful addressing is useless and shouldn't be taught anywhere outside history lessons.